# Modifying Wordpress official docker image to work on subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am planning to use Wordpress official docker image on Amazon ECS. The problem is that instead working on the root path `https://www.example.com/`, I need it to work on a subdirectory path `https://www.example.com/blog/`.

To modify this I am planning to create a new Docker image based on the official Wordpress docker image.

My current Dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM wordpress:6.0.1-apache

# Copying to premium so user can access it through
# domain/blog
RUN cd /var/www/html; \
    mkdir blog; \
    cp !\(blog\) blog; \
    # We copy the wordpress instance to subdirectory and disable
    # access to the root instance.
    echo "Hello World!" > /var/www/html/index.php;
```

However this doesn't work. When I access `https://www.example.com/blog` it shows **Forbidden**.
The log shows this

```
[autoindex:error] [pid 23] [client 172.30.0.1:61822] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/blog/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

It seems that the image does not copy the wordpress library.

```
wordpress % docker compose exec wordpress bash
root@63d417de7f31:/var/www/html# ls
index.php  blog  wp-config.php  wp-content
root@63d417de7f31:/var/www/html# ls -al
total 32
drwxrwxrwx 4 www-data www-data 4096 Aug  5 06:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     4096 Aug  2 07:49 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       13 Aug  5 06:06 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Aug  5 06:06 blog
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 5584 Aug  5 06:13 wp-config.php
drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data www-data 4096 Aug  5 06:13 wp-content
root@63d417de7f31:/var/www/html# ls -al blog/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Aug  5 06:06 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 www-data www-data 4096 Aug  5 06:13 ..
root@63d417de7f31:/var/www/html# exit
```

What should I do?

## Update 1

When I trim the Dockerfile to just the base image like this,

```
FROM wordpress:6.0.1-apache
```

the wordpress files are copied into `/var/www/html`.

```
% docker compose exec wordpress bash
root@f9ad22323268:/var/www/html# ls
index.php    wp-admin          wp-config-sample.php  wp-includes    wp-mail.php   xmlrpc.php
license.txt  wp-blog-header.php    wp-config.php         wp-links-opml.php  wp-settings.php
readme.html  wp-comments-post.php  wp-content        wp-load.php    wp-signup.php
wp-activate.php  wp-config-docker.php  wp-cron.php       wp-login.php   wp-trackback.php
```

## Update 2

I tried using this

```
FROM wordpress:6.0.1-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html/blog
```

This copies the Wordpress installation both in `/var/www/html` and `/var/www/html/blog`. This still fits the requirement, however I want to remove the one in `/var/www/html/`. I tried rewriting to `/var/www/html/index.php` like below

```
FROM wordpress:6.0.1-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html/blog

RUN echo "Hello World!" > /var/www/html/index.php
```

But it's not rewritten. Seems like it's being rewritten from the entrypoint

https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give Apache user access to blog directory. By adding following to Dockerfile

```
 RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/blog
```